# how can I read float string and format it to mpq_t in gmp

Tags: gmp

I can use gmp_sscanf to read float number like 0x12f.3p3 to mpf_t. However, I can't use it to read as mpq_t. If I fisrt read it as mpf_t, and convert it to mpq_t. The result is not right because of the precision. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use more precision for the mpf_t?

Comment: @MarcGlisse I don't think that will work. For some number it can't be exactly the same as the original number even through you put more bits. And I wander why gcc use mpf_t rather than mpq_t?

Comment: @MarcGlisse For example, if I save 0.3 as mpf_t, it will be 0.299. If I add more bits, it will be 0.299999, but it is still not 0.3. It seems gcc save float literal as mpf_t. I don't know why they won't use mpq_t.

Comment: C++ interprets float literals as `double`.